# IdentitySever4 UserInteractionOptions Login url not called

Tags: identityserver4

I have set the LoginUrl and ConsentUrl for UserInteraction pointing to our MVC web application. However the issue is that the LoginUrl does not get called when ConsentUrl is defined. The LoginUrl only gets called when I dont set the Consent Url. I am not sure how to config this as this is not clearly outlined in the documentation. Can I only set one or the other? So I not need the LoginUrl if I define the ConsentUrl?
After I authenticate the user, redirect to the identity server with the details what the identity server uses to validate the authentication. This part works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured this out. My cookie was not expired so was identity server was considering me as already logged in. It was hence sending me over to the consent endpoint.